# Print two lines in to single line but with alternate characters from each source line

Tags: python

I have file.txt containing two lines :

```
this is one
and my pen
```

Output should be like print each colum of every line in single row :

```
tahnids imsy opneen
```

How can we print this output in Python?

I tried the following but I'm stuck on jumping between alternate characters in each line. I'm looking for a generic solution whether one line or two line or more.

```py
file=open('file.txt','r')
list1=[x.rstrip('\n') for x in file]
for i in list1:
    n=len(i)
    c=0
    while c<n:
        print(i[c],end=" ")
        c=c+1
    break
```

This it is printing only "ta".

Comment: The `zip` function in Python lets you pair up items from two lists. If you still need help, you should [edit] your question, rather than heap on comments which nobody will see.

Comment: I attempted to update your question but I had to guess your indentation. Please review and edit further if necessary.

Comment: Why do you `break`? I'm guessing the indentation on that is wrong actually?

Comment: How should the program behave if the lines are not all the same length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's debatable whether oneliners are good for this sort of thing but itertools can do this.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> with open('/path/to/file') as data:
...     # could be just data.readlines() if you don't mind the newlines
...     a, b = [l.strip() for l in data.readlines()]
>>> # a = "this is one"                                                                                                                  
>>> # b = "and my pen"
>>> ''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip(a, b))
'tahnids  miys  poenn'
```

I'm also not sure your expected result is correct. If you're alternating all the characters, the two spaces should be together.

If your file has more than two lines, replacing `a, b = ...` with `lines = ...` and then using `zip(*lines)` should work for any number.

If you want to avoid itertools

```
''.join(''.join(x) for x in zip(a, b))
```

To include all the characters, even when the lines are not the same length, you can use itertools again.

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest
''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue='')))
# or
''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(*lines, fillvalue='')))
```

Comment: can this be without itertools module.
`b=""
for x,y in zip(s1,s2):
    b += x+y
print(b) ` .  but problem is if lines are not equal in lengh zip will no pick that pair;
so either fill line with zeros for missing characters or spaces.

Comment: @tech_guy probably but itertools is part of the standard library so why would you?

Comment: Added alternative

Comment: oh nice so join function itself extrac all values from generator object @holloway

Comment: The inner join joins each pair of characters. The outer join then joins the pairs.

Comment: If the lines aren't equal length, what behaviour would you like?

Comment: if not equal length it should print all characters of lines. That is what zip is not taking care

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196884/discussion-between-tech-guy-and-holloway).

Comment: If your file has more than two lines, replacing a, b = ... with lines = ... and then using zip(lines) should work for any number.

` lines = [l.strip() for l in data.readlines()]

   print(''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip(lines))))` . not working as expected